# TypeError: update() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given : Python

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting `TypeError`: `update() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. I have no idea about why this error occurs. if anybody could figure out where i'm doing thing wrong then would be much appreciated. thank you so much in advance.

serializers.py :

```
class ShopOwnerOrderManageSerializer(Serializer):
    invoice_no = CharField(read_only=True)
    shopowner_expected_date  = CharField(allow_blank=True)
    shopowner_estimated_time = CharField(allow_blank=True)
    status = CharField(allow_blank=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CarOwnerShopConfirm
        fields= ['shopowner_expected_date','shopowner_estimated_time','status']

    def update(self,validated_data):
        shopowner_expected_date        = validated_data['shopowner_expected_date'] 
        shopowner_estimated_time       = validated_data['shopowner_estimated_time'] 
        status                         = validated_data['status']

        shopconfirm_obj = CarOwnerShopConfirm.objects.update(
                shopowner_expected_date   =   shopowner_expected_date,
                shopowner_estimated_time = shopowner_estimated_time,
                status = status
                )       
        shopconfirm_obj.save()
    
        return validated_data
```

Comment: `update` in a `Serializer` takes three parameters: `self`, `instance` and `validated_Data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update` in a `Serializer` takes *three* parameters: `self`, *`instance*` and *validated data*. Normally the database does *not* save the changes in the database, but only *updates* the instance. The view for example can then later decide to update the database by calling `.save()`.

You probably also want to use a `ModelSerializer`, since a simple `Serializer` does not take into account the `Meta` inner class, and thus will not "bind" the serializer fields to these of the object:

```
class ShopOwnerOrderManageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    invoice_no = CharField(read_only=True)
    shopowner_expected_date  = CharField(allow_blank=True)
    shopowner_estimated_time = CharField(allow_blank=True)
    status = CharField(allow_blank=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CarOwnerShopConfirm
        fields= ['shopowner_expected_date','shopowner_estimated_time','status']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.shopowner_expected_date = validated_data.get('shopowner_expected_date', instance.shopowner_expected_date)
        instance.shopowner_estimated_time = validated_data.get('shopowner_estimated_time', intance.shopowner_estimated_time)
        instance.status = validated_data.get('status', instance.status)
        return instance
```

Since however Django's `ModelSerializer` will implement the `update` like we did here, you can *omit* it completely:

```
class ShopOwnerOrderManageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    invoice_no = CharField(read_only=True)
    shopowner_expected_date  = CharField(allow_blank=True)
    shopowner_estimated_time = CharField(allow_blank=True)
    status = CharField(allow_blank=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CarOwnerShopConfirm
        fields= ['shopowner_expected_date','shopowner_estimated_time','status']

    # no update
```

Comment: As per you said, it's only updates the instance, but not permanently saving the data. but i want to store the update data as permanently .

Comment: @xxnora: yes, but normally you do that by calling `.save()` on the serializer. By doing this in the `.update()` you are not really respecting the "contract" of the method, and hence if you reuse it in a view, it might result in unpredictable behavior.

Comment: @xxnora: furthermore because the updating is what the Django `ModelSerializer` does you can actually omit the `.update` method.

Comment: yes. I got really helpful. thank you very much. wanna grab a coffee from me? :D